# How to gain access to Digital Ocean account with TFA enabled but smartphone uninstalled?

Tags: digital-ocean

The only option in DigitalOcean login page is `Enter backup code`.. which I didn't saved.

The hard thing is, trying to contact Digital Ocean support require me to login. Which is the whole problem.

That's why I ask this here. Or, am I totally shut here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should contact Digital Ocean support here: https://www.digitalocean.com/company/contact/

Comment: Great. Thanks! Found their email, and sent. I hope I can get access to it.